# Financial calculations needed to be performed on a dataset containing multiple categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, finance

I have the following dataset that is related to the value of building permits categorized by various Canadian Provinces (i.e. British Columbia, Alberta, Ontario) and Type of Permit (Residential, Non-residential, Governmental etc.).

| Date | Jurisdiction | Structure Type | Value of Permit (Million $) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01 | Alberta | Total non-residential | 1214.214 |
| 2017-02 | Alberta | Total residential | 1096.826 |
| 2017-03 | British Columbia | Total non-residential | 1202.425 |
| 2017-04 | British Columbia | Total residential | 1071.843 |

I want to calculate various financial parameters such as:

**3 Months moving Average:** For example, in the case of March 2022, the moving average will be:

*('Permit Value March 2022' + 'Permit Value February 2022' + 'Permit Value January 2022')/3*

**Year-Over-Year Growth**: For example, in the case of June 2022, the YOY Growth will be:

*('Permit Value June 2022' - 'Permit Value June 2021')/('Permit Value June 2021')*

**Year-to-Date Growth**: For example, in the case of April 2022, the YTD Growth will be:

*((SUM of Permit Value for the Month of January, February, March, April 2022) - (SUM of Permit Value for the Month of January, February, March, April 2021)) / (SUM of Permit Value for the Month of January, February, March, April 2021)*

I need to perform the above calculations for each combination of 'Jursdiction' and 'Structure Type' columns.

The end result should look something like this but it should not be restricted to one Jursidiction or Type of Structure

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfJ5G.png)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is the YOY and YTD calculations for each row? If not how do you aggregate them?

Comment: Yes, values are needed to be calculated for each row. Three new columns are needed to be created i.e. 3-Month moving average, YOY and YTD.

Comment: Ok, can you provide a little example?

Comment: I have altered my question and included an image for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using the limited data you have given above, this produces NA everywhere (but will work, as seen below):

```
def statistics(x):
    # columns to be returned (all input columns, and the new three)
    cols = list(x.columns) + ["3-month_ma", "YOY Growth", "YTD Growth"]
    # sort the data to ensure that the index is ascending (required for the window and shift)
    x.sort_index(inplace=True)

    # 3-month moving average
    # rolling window of 3, and the mean
    x["3-month_ma"] = x["Value of Permit (Million $)"].rolling(3).mean()

    # YOY Growth
    # (current value - value 12 rows prior) / value 12 rows prior
    x["YOY Growth"] = (x["Value of Permit (Million $)"] - x["Value of Permit (Million $)"].shift(12)) / x["Value of Permit (Million $)"].shift(12)

    # YTD Growth
    # initial calculation for cumulative sum over the year
    x["YTD calc"] = x.assign(_year=lambda x: x.index.year).groupby('_year')["Value of Permit (Million $)"].cumsum()
    # (YTD - YTD 12 rows prior) / YTD 12 rows prior
    x["YTD Growth"] = (x["YTD calc"] - x["YTD calc"].shift(12)) / x["YTD calc"].shift(12)

    # return the required columns (which are those except the "YTD calc")
    return x[cols]

df.groupby(["Jurisdiction", "Structure Type"]).apply(statistics)
#                Jurisdiction         Structure Type  Value of Permit (Million $)  3-month_ma  YOY Growth  YTD Growth
#Date                                                                                                                
#2017-01-01           Alberta  Total non-residential                     1214.214         NaN         NaN         NaN
#2017-02-01           Alberta      Total residential                     1096.826         NaN         NaN         NaN
#2017-03-01  British Columbia  Total non-residential                     1202.425         NaN         NaN         NaN
#2017-04-01  British Columbia      Total residential                     1071.843         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Before this, I ensured that the Date column was the index, and that these were in datetime format:

```
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

To test this on more substantial data, I have created a test dataset and run the same code:

```
dts = pd.date_range("01-01-2017", "01-01-2022", freq="MS")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Jurisdiction", "Structure Type", "Value of Permit (Million $)"])

df["Date"] = list(dts) * 4
df["Jurisdiction"] = len(dts) * 2 * ["Alberta"] + len(dts) * 2 * ["British Columbia"]
df["Structure Type"] = (len(dts) * ["Total non-residential"] + len(dts) * ["Total residential"]) * 2
df["Value of Permit (Million $)"] = np.random.randint(400, 600, len(dts)*4)

# Output from `groupby apply`:
           Jurisdiction         Structure Type  Value of Permit (Million $)  3-month_ma  YOY Growth  YTD Growth
Date                                                                                                           
2017-01-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          538         NaN         NaN         NaN
2017-02-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          485         NaN         NaN         NaN
2017-03-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          507  510.000000         NaN         NaN
2017-04-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          594  528.666667         NaN         NaN
2017-05-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          444  515.000000         NaN         NaN
2017-06-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          405  481.000000         NaN         NaN
2017-07-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          422  423.666667         NaN         NaN
2017-08-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          413  413.333333         NaN         NaN
2017-09-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          415  416.666667         NaN         NaN
2017-10-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          558  462.000000         NaN         NaN
2017-11-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          484  485.666667         NaN         NaN
2017-12-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          552  531.333333         NaN         NaN
2018-01-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          487  507.666667   -0.094796   -0.094796
2018-02-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          475  504.666667   -0.020619   -0.059629
2018-03-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          544  502.000000    0.072978   -0.015686
2018-04-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          472  497.000000   -0.205387   -0.068738
2018-05-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          496  504.000000    0.117117   -0.036604
2018-06-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          502  490.000000    0.239506    0.001009
2018-07-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          552  516.666667    0.308057    0.039175
2018-08-01      Alberta  Total non-residential                          563  539.000000    0.363196    0.074317
```

Note a few assumptions:

- As mentioned above, I have assumed that the Date column is the index and is in datetime format.
- There is data for every month for each of the different groups (jurisdiction and structure type), as this is required for the `shift` and `rolling` to work correctly.  If this is not the case, then the shift and rolling could be applied differently.